# Decrement value by 1 MS Access SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm facing a problem with decrementing value with MS Access database.

I get an error

> Syntax error in UPDATE Statement

My code:

```
connection.Open();
command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = " update Cards set Count = Count - 1 where Type=" + ct + " ";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: what is the `Type` datatype?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and to fix your problem.

Comment: The Type is text

Comment: parameters not solving the problem I tried

Comment: Count is a reserved word.  Put it in brackets: `[Count]`  Terrible choice for a column name, by the way.  Use NumCards or something like that.

Comment: you just need to add single quotes around the type value like this: 

`command.CommandText = " update Cards set Count = Count - 1 where Type='" + ct + "' ";`

Comment: @themehio Stop it.  Parameters is the only "safe way" to fix this mistake.  If you submit code like that at a job interview, you aren't getting the job.

Comment: Same problem when put in brackets.

Comment: Yeah, you've hit another reserved word.  `[Type]`

Comment: Thaaaanks Mister @LarsTech the brackets solved it ,It caused by reserved words

Comment: Mister @LarsTech I have another question, I want  to change many values in my table by **card type** how can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide an actual error.
My guess is that count is a keyword and has to be put in square brackets like so [count]
and do use parameters, see Joel's answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not certain, but I strongly suspect it's missing single quotes around `ct`. Fix it like this:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("connection string here"))
using (var command = new OleDbCommand("update Cards set Count = Count - 1 where Type= ?", connection))
{
    //have to guess at the OleDbType value. Use the actual column type and length from the database
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = ct;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

There are several other important fixes in this pattern, too.